# Share drawable image to other apps properly (sharing PNG to Whatsapp fails without FileProvider)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, whatsapp

I'm creating an Android app where the user can select one of several images to share (which are stored in the `drawable` folder) and the app opens up a standard ACTION_SEND chooser to allow them to share it to any app that supports PNGs, like so:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.owlswipe.imagesharer/" + getImage());

Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "share to an app"));

public int getImage() {
return R.drawable.firstimage;
}
```

However, if the user selects to share it to Whatsapp, it doesn't work properly: instead of interpreting it as an image (like if you normally share a photo to Whatsapp) it thinks it's a document called "Untitled" and does not show as an image.

[image: Whatsapp problem]

Opening this Untitled document on a computer reveals it's called `DOC-20180721-WA0012.` with no file extension! Manually adding a `png` to the end of the filename reveals the correct image.

Making this weirder (but definitely solvable somehow!):

- If the user chooses to open the image in an SMS app, for example, the image appears normally.
- This has happened with multiple devices (Pixel 2 on P beta and Nokia 2 on 7.1.1)
- This issue does not happen with other apps, where PNGs can be sent via Whatsapp like a normal image (though they do seem to be automatically converted to JPEGs by Whatsapp).

---

What can I do to make sure Whatsapp sees my image as a proper PNG file? Alternatively, how do I properly share a pre-loaded image from my app such that every app can interpret it correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by properly implementing a FileProvider! [This guide helped me so much](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/share-files-using-fileprovider), but I'll give a brief summary here.

Within the `application` tag of your Manifest, start declaring your new FileProvider like so:

```
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:grantUriPermissions="true"
android:exported="false"
android:authorities="${applicationId}">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>

</provider>
```

Then, create a new directory called `xml` (control-click on your `res` in Android Studio and go to New > Directory). Then, create a new file within `xml` called `file_provider_paths` (control-click on the new `xml` directory, and go to New > File, and name it `file_provider_paths.xml`). Add this code to that new xml file:

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
    <files-path name="files" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Finally, use it in your MainActivity or wherever like so:

```
// create new Intent
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// set flag to give temporary permission to external app to use your FileProvider
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

// generate URI, I defined authority as the application ID in the Manifest, the last param is file I want to open
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, imageFile);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

// Set type to only show apps that can open your PNG file
intent.setType("image/png");

// start activity!
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "send"));
```

To get that `imageFile` from an image in my `drawable` directory, I first converted it to a Bitmap, and then onto a File object, like so:

```
// create file from drawable image
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.yourbeautifulimage);

File filesDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
File imageFile = new File(filesDir, "ABeautifulFilename.png");

OutputStream os;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os); // 100% quality
    os.flush();
    os.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
}
```

And you're done, every app can see your shared image now!

Comment: If you have made changes to your app's manifest file, make sure to rebuild your app to apply the changes.